# filter a string to remove disallowed characters to compose an URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I'm trying to make URL-friendly links for the blog on my portfolio.
So I would like to obtain links something like site/journal/post/{title}

Obviously Journal is my controller, but let's say my title would be 'mysite.com goes live!' I would like to have a valid url like site/journal/post/mysitecom-goes-live where all disallowed characters are removed.

How would I transform 'mysite.com goes live!' to 'site/journal/post/mysitecom-goes-live' in CodeIgniter based on the characters in $config['permitted_uri_chars']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the url helper

```
$this->load->helper('url');

$blog_slug = url_title('Mysite.com Goes live!');

echo $blog_slug //mysitecom-site-goes-live 
// might differ slightly, but it'll do what you want.
```

to generate url-friendly links.

Store this value in a field in your blog table (url_title/url_slug) whatever.

make a function:

```
class Journal extends controller
{
   //make your index/constructor etc

   function view($post)
   {
     $this->blog_model->get_post($post);
     // etc - your model returns the correct post,
     // then process that data and pass it to your view
   }
}
```

your blog_model has a method get_post that uses CI's

`$this->db->where('url_title', $post);`

hope that makes sense.

then when you access the page:

`site.com/journal/view/mysite-goes-live`

the function will pick up "mysite-goes-live" and pass it to the view() function, which in turn looks up the appropriate blog entry in the database.

Comment: thanks a lot, there was no need to explain everything so thoroughly thought (although I appreciate the effort a lot)

Comment: great answer, very comprehensive

Comment: I still get 'The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.' error even when I use url_title(), meaning that its not removing all special characters specified in permitted_uri_chars in config. What can I do??